# Editing address strings by adding missing words in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list of addresses that are not perfectly formatted. The majority share the same basic structure, but around a fifth have not been inputted correctly.

`df1` contains 24 addresses, each as a single string. My aim is to find the addresses that appear to have words or numbers missing and add them into each string where they are most likely to belong.

My approach has been to count the number of times each unique word/number is present in the dataframe. Words that appear in 80% or more of the rows are identified as the ones that need to be added to each addresses. Any missing words need to be added in the 'correct' position based on the formatting of the addresses which contain all the addressing elements.

I can identify the words that need to be added, but I have not found a way of adding the words into each string if they are not present; nor have I found a way of ensuring they are added into the correct place within the string. This is further complicated as in my real dataset the formatting of the address is not constant across areas i.e. in this example the building number and road name are meant to be the 3rd and 4th address elements. Sometimes they will be the 1st and 2nd, 2nd and 3rd etc. So the solution I have been trying to develop also needs to be dynamic.

This is my sample dataset:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("apt 23 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 47 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 24 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 3 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 44 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 88 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 7 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 41 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 55 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 19 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "85 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 12 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 452 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 1 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "99 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 73 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "74 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 75 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 63 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 48 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 123 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 56 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "6 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 2 6 roadname cityville b11abc"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

This is my method for identifying the words that need to be added:

```
df1_words <- as.data.frame(table(t(as.data.frame(as.list(unlist(strsplit(df1$V1, " ")))))))
df1_words_80 <- subset(df1_words, Freq >= round(nrow(df1)/100*80))
```

This is the output I am after:

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c("apt 23 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 47 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 24 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 3 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 44 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 88 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 7 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 41 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 55 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 19 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 85 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 12 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 452 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 1 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 99 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 73 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 74 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 75 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 63 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 48 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 123 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 56 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 6 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 2 6 roadname cityville b11abc"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**Edit**
After applying ikop's solution to a real dataset I have come across a problem when the list contains addresses that vary in length. The problem I think is that some short addresses (e.g. containing 5 words) are trying to have frequent words normally found at position's 6,7,8,9 etc. in a string inserted into them which is impossible, hence creating an error. I can think of two solutions to this, either count backwards rather than forwards, or, possibly the easier option (and the one I think would work best for my particular needs), just ignore rows that contain strings that are uncommonly short.

The problem I am having can be replicated when using `df3` with ikop's solution

```
df3 <- data.frame(V1=c("apt really long name 23 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 47 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 24 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 3 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 44 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 88 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 7 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 41 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 55 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 19 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "85 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 12 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 452 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 1 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "99 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 73 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "74 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt 75 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 63 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 48 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 123 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 56 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "6 5 roadname cityville b11abc", "apt really long name 2 6 roadname cityville b11abc"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacky solution that will get you most of the way.

```
## For each word that appears in at least 80% of the rows compute 
## the most frequent position it appears in:
library(dplyr)
splitList <- strsplit(df1$V1, " ")
wordVec <- unique(unlist(splitList))
wordFrequencyDf <- lapply(wordVec, function(theWord){
                    freqWord <- sum(unlist(splitList) == theWord)
                    posVec <- unlist(lapply(splitList, function(x) which(x == theWord)))
                    mostFreqPos <- sort(table(posVec), decreasing = TRUE)[1] %>% names %>% as.numeric
                    data.frame(theWord, freqWord,mostFreqPos)
                }) %>% 
        do.call('rbind',.) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(theWord = as.character(theWord)) %>%
        dplyr::filter(freqWord >= round(nrow(df1)*0.8)) %>%
        dplyr::arrange(mostFreqPos)

## Now loop over those words and insert the word in the relevant
## position if necessary:
for (ii in seq(along = wordFrequencyDf$theWord)){
    splitList <- lapply(splitList, function(x){
                relPos <- wordFrequencyDf$mostFreqPos[ii]
                if (x[relPos] != wordFrequencyDf$theWord[ii]){
                    if (relPos == 1){
                        strBefore <- NULL                       
                    } else {
                        strBefore <- x[1:(relPos-1)]
                    }                       
                    if (relPos > length(x)){
                        strAfter <- NULL                        
                    } else {
                        strAfter <- x[relPos:length(x)]
                    }                   
                    x <- c(strBefore, wordFrequencyDf$theWord[ii], strAfter)
                }
                x
            })  
}

## Paste list together into a single string again:
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = sapply(splitList, function(x) paste(x, collapse = " ")))
```

**Result:**

```
df2
#                                                               V1
# 1                             apt 23 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 2                             apt 47 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 3                             apt 24 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 4                              apt 3 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 5                             apt 44 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 6                             apt 88 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 7                              apt 7 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 8                             apt 41 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 9                             apt 55 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 10                            apt 19 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 11                            apt 85 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 12                            apt 12 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 13                           apt 452 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 14                             apt 1 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 15                            apt 99 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 16                            apt 73 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 17                            apt 74 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 18                            apt 75 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 19                            apt 63 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 20                            apt 48 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 21                           apt 123 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 22                            apt 56 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 23                             apt 6 5 roadname cityville b11abc
# 24 apt 2 5 roadname cityville b11abc 6 roadname cityville b11abc
```

You can see that the method failed in the last line. Here the original line did not have a `"5"` at position 3 (as the code expected). But the problem is that the building number was not missing entirely, the string just contained a different building number. The code, however interpreted this as a missing building number and inserted the `"5"` at position 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have applied it to my real dataset and it works almost all the time. However, there is a problem when the list of addresses contains strings of varying lengths. I have tried to edit your solution to basically ignore rows that contain uncommonly short strings, but am not having much luck. I have added an example to the question which demonstrates the error I am coming across.